# Embedding Cascading XML files

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I'd like to embed the OpenCV Haar cascading files inside my headers instead of using an absolute path.

This would avoid annoying path problems when working with my colleagues.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just include the XML inside the same folder as the file? That way when you share the folder and code it is always the same. In my experience I have found that this works very well and helps keep projects organized nicely.

```
projectFolder  <-- What you send to colleagues
    cv.cpp
    makefile
    xmlFolder
        cascading.xml
```

Comment: It happened, and two colleague succeeded in deleting it from the project. Embedding would be the safest option.

Comment: I cannot think of an easier way than converting the XML file into a constant char* array and replacing symbols like " with \" and things like that so it is readable by the program. This would hard code it into your program so that it would always be there